# Using jsPDF-AutoTable with large tables

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a need to print a large table across multiple pages which contains both header rows and a “header" column. Representative of what I would like to achieve is:

https://github.com/EricG-Personal/table_print/blob/master/table.png

I do not want the contents of any cell to be clipped, split between pages, or auto-scaled to be smaller. Each page should have the appropriate header rows and each page should have the appropriate header column (the ID column).

The only aspect not depicted is that some of the cells would contain image data.

Can I achieve this with jsPDF-AutoTable?

Comment: Nope, not possible. It is an interesting problem though and would be interesting to add that feature for sure!

Comment: I can add a feature request issue to your github page.